# finding the Rank and basis of null space of this matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

[image]

Please help me with this question.
The question is to find the rank of the matrix and then the basis of the null space, I first put the matrix A in reduced row echelon form and then I wrote the operations that I did at the side so it's clear how I got the values, I got the answer as rank = 2 because there r two pivot entry columns, but in the marking scheme they tell that the rank is 2 because there r two rows of 0, but this is something we never learnt in school , I was taught to put in rref(A) and make a entry of a column 1 and the rest 0. And I also want to ask is that whether we can multiply a row by a scalar multiple ? For example can I multiply row 2 by -1 to get 0 1 -3 4 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the correct rank of $A$, indeed $\text{rank}(A) = 2$. First, you have the row-reduced echelon form incorrect...it should be $$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & -5 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & -3 & 4 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \,.$$
In regards to your question about multiplying rows by scalars in the process of row reduction, this is perfectly fine. Writing the above in parametric form, we have
$$\begin{cases} x_1 &= \,\,\,\, 5x_3-x_4 \\ x_2 &= \,\,\,\,3x_3 -4x_4 \end{cases}$$
with $x_3,x_4$ free. This is equivalent to the vector solution
$$\vec{x} = \begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \\ x_4 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 5 \\3 \\1\\0 \end{pmatrix}x_3 + \begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ -4 \\0\\1 \end{pmatrix}x_4 \,\,.$$
Thus, the basis for the null space that you were seeking is
$$ \mathscr{B} =\left\{ \begin{pmatrix} 5 \\3 \\1\\0 \end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ -4 \\0\\1 \end{pmatrix} \right\} \,.$$

Comment: Thank you very much :D one more thing , Is the rank 2 because it has two pivot entry columns or because (like in marking scheme) there are two rows with zeros?

Comment: In short, **both**. The *rank* of a matrix is the largest collection of linearly independent columns of the matrix, or equivalently, the largest collection of linearly independent rows of the matrix. Upon row-reduction, you are computing this largest collection by determining which rows are linearly independent.  There are many ways, however, to determine rank and you have mentioned a couple in this case.  If all of the rows are linearly independent (i.e., there are no free variables, or equivalently, there are no zero rows), then the matrix is said to have *full rank*. @Tharindu

Comment: Note: a matrix can only have full rank if it is square, but this is not necessarily the case.

Comment: No problem! Glad to help! @Tharindu

Comment: Oh can I ask one more thing if you don't mind :)

Comment: Shoot @Tharindu

Comment: Ok in the next part, like can u see the matrix A , there is a 9 in last column, instead of the 9 they say it's alpha , a number which is not equal to 9, and they have asked for the rank, how to do that ?

Comment: I don't see a $9$ in the last row.

Comment: In last column sorry

Comment: Go through the same procedure you did to row-reduce, except replace the $9$ with $\alpha \neq 9$. Simply treat $\alpha$ as any other number in your matrix. Then, depending on the row-reduced echelon form, your rank might be different.

Comment: Thank you , you have no idea how much this mean to me , it's my further math a level exam in a few days.

Comment: Again, no problem! @Tharindu

Comment: **GOOD LUCK**!! @Tharindu

Comment: Got it right :D thanks :D